# Mutate React state of a JSON object Storing Array as a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

How to push or remove an element from this?

```
  const [addIconMenuList, setAddIconMenuList] = useState({
    "body": ["Logo", "Chest Pocket", "Tag"],
    "hood": ["Logo"],
    "sleeves": ["Cuffs"]
  })
```

```
    setAddIconMenuList((prevState) => {
      prevState[rightNavbarType].filter((item) => {
        return item !== type
      })
    })
```

and I am trying this which is not working

Comment: You should return the `prevState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `setAddIconMenuList` you are not returning anything from the function. Try adding a return like this.

```
setAddIconMenuList((prevState) => {
  return prevState[rightNavbarType].filter((item) => {
    return item !== type
  })
})
```

Edit: or you can get rid of the brackets surrounding the function body. A single statement like that is automatically returned.

```
setAddIconMenuList((prevState) => 
  prevState[rightNavbarType].filter((item) => {
    return item !== type
  })
)
```

---

**Edit: keeping the rest of the state**

To keep the rest of the previous state and not just return a filtered list you can try something like this:

```
setAddIconMenuList((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    [rightNavbarType]: prevState[rightNavbarType].filter((item) => {
      return item !== type
    })
  }
})
```

The `...prevState` separates the previous object into its individual pieces, so you will have everything that was in the state before, returned in this object.

`[rightNavbarType]` is using ES6 computed property syntax so you can access the property you want, such as "body". Then you set "body" to the new filtered array.

Comment: It returns only the array now, not the JSON Object. As now, it returns ["Chest Pocket", "Tag"] not the object with changed array. @D. Smith

Comment: Yes `filter`  will return an array with elements that passed the internal condition. So to get the rest of the state back as well, you need some kind of spreading of the old state, and then modify the array to the specific key in the object. Let me edit my response to add a code snippet to show that.